# WinRT custom control - could not bind DependencyProperty of type IMvxCommand, but could bind when type changed to RelayCommand or ICommand

Tags: windows-runtime, icommand

At the WP2W8 London event yesterday I tried to port an existing WP7 custom control across to WinRT (May 31st Release Candidate version)

This custom control had a property which was declared like:

```cs
public IMvxCommand Command
{
    get { return (IMvxCommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(IMvxCommand), typeof(IconWithTextMenuItem), new PropertyMetadata(null));

private void OnTap(object sender, CantRememberExactEventArgs e)
{
    if (Command == null)
        return;

    if (CommandParameter != null)
        Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
    else
        Command.Execute();
}
```

No matter what I tried I couldn't get this to bind - the output window debug binding error always reported that the binding could not convert type `MvxRelayCommand` to `IMvxCommand`

However, if I changed the `IMvxCommand` to `MvxRelayCommand` or `ICommand` then the binding worked.

The inheritance tree here was `MvxRelayCommand` inherits from `IMvxCommand` inherits from `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` - but I do suspect WinRT may be doing some funky type redirection with `ICommand` in the background.

Does anyone have any insight into whether `IMvxCommand` or `ICommand` dependency properties can be used in WinRT custom controls?

---

Update - an example project is: https://github.com/slodge/WinRTInterfaceBindingProblem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got nothing back from MS on this.

But from the sample, I'm guessing its just a bug that we have to live with:

https://github.com/slodge/WinRTInterfaceBindingProblem/tree/master/App1

Answer (score 2):

I think `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` can be used in WinRT controls. In your example, you may just have to declare the dependency property as a `ICommand` rather than `IMvxCommand`.

Comment: Thanks - I agree - but I actually wanted to use something in the extended interface - puzzled about what is going on here :/

Comment: I've +1'd the answer - but also corrected the question a little to include the ICommand info and to include a sample repo - sorry this makes your answer look odd!

Answer (score 0):

in WP7 `ICommand` is in the `System.Windows.Input` namespace. In Metra XAML its in the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Input` namespace. It seems you are referencing a library that relies on the WP7 binaries which wont compile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The story of ICommand inside WinRT is a strange one - I can't comment on it in detail because I don't yet understand it... However, you are definitely wrong about "won't compile" - System.Windows.ICommand compiles and runs fine on WinRT - e.g. see https://github.com/slodge/WinRTInterfaceBindingProblem - and I've been told it has been specifically included as part of MS's efforts to improve code portability.

Comment: It may compile (my mistake), but a Metro XAML Button will want to bind to a Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ICommand, which means your implementation wont work

Comment: Sorry - but that's not the case for portable code. see the series on http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2012/03/understanding-portable-library-by_14.html Also please try running the github sample - ICommand clearly compiles and runs - it's just the intermediate interface that doesn't bind at run time.

Comment: Your question was to why your code doesnt work. The answer is that its not compatible (and would not participate in any portability - rightly or wrongly). Ive answered your question giving you techncal reasons why it doesnt work. The answer is the correct one

Comment: As I said in my first comment... "Thanks for your answer". I agree with your observation that ICommand exists in 2 places. However, I'm afraid I can't mark your answer is "correct" this stage... not least because 1. the sample - https://github.com/slodge/WinRTInterfaceBindingProblem/tree/master/App1 - does not reference any WP7 binaries; 2. because it does compile; and 3. because if I change ICommand in the sample to reference Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ICommand then it won't compile - see  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/7f6cb203-4a49-4b9a-a0a6-960363cdc44a